# In BEA Tuxedo does it make sense to call tpfree after tpreturn?

Tags: c, return, tuxedo

I see this way too often in the codebase I'm currently working in:

```
int obtained_number = 5;
char *answer = tpalloc(15);
sprintf(answer, "num:%d", obtained_number);
tpreturn(TPSUCCESS, 0, answer, answerSize, 0);
tpfree(answer);//why?
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13203_01/tuxedo/tux71/html/rf3c65.htm):

> tpreturn() acts like a return statement in the C language (that is, when tpreturn() is called, the service routine returns to the BEA Tuxedo system dispatcher).

If this is so, I guess the service finishes at that point and `tpfree()` is never called. When the service is called again, it starts in the main method again, instead of where the execution finished last time.

Is this correct? Should I report this unnecesary use of `tpfree()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tpreturn() actually performs longjmp() and no code after tpreturn() is executed. When the  service is called again, it starts from the beginning of service function.

In your case it means that tpfree() is never executed and it should not - tpreturn() takes care of buffer you pass to it (releases, caches for the next call, etc.)

What is worse for C++ code

```
std::string obtained_str = "5";
char *answer = tpalloc(15);
sprintf(answer, "str:%s", obtained_str.c_str());
tpreturn(TPSUCCESS, 0, answer, answerSize, 0);
```

destructor for obtained_str will not be called and you will have a memory leak.